# Deploy Eve app on apache2 webserver

Tags: python, mongodb, apache, mod-wsgi, eve

I have a simple Eve app to serve data from mongodb.
I tried to follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) tutorial
Launching it through python virtual env works fine:

```
(venv) user@ID17974:/var/www/eve/eve$ python run.py
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And calling it provides the correct info (I can find, project etcetc)

The problem arises when I try to put it through apache.

My eve.wsgi is this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/eve/")

from run import app as application
application.secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxx'
```

My eve.conf for apache looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName server.dot
                ServerAdmin name@serve.dot
                WSGIScriptAlias /eve /var/www/eve/eve.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/eve/eve/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/eve/eve/static
                <Directory /var/www/eve/eve/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

while my 000-default.conf like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName server.dot

    ServerAdmin name@server.dot
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    Allow from localhost ::1
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/genghis">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd2
        Require valid-user
        Allow from localhost ::1
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
</Directory>


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =server.dot
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin name@server.dot
    ServerName shiny.server.dot
    DocumentRoot /srv/shiny-server/

<Location / >
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    AllowOverride all                       
</Location>


<Proxy /shiny/>
 Order deny,allow
 AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
        Allow from localhost ::1
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
  </Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3838/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3838/
  ProxyPass / wss://localhost:3838/
  ProxyPassReverse / wss://localhost:3838/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =shiny.server.dot
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>


# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

When I try to access server.dot/eve/collection I get a 404 error.

Moreover I would like to serve more then one collection.

Comment: What web framework are you using? What URL sub paths does it have handlers for? Based on your configuration must have handler for sub path of ``/collection``, not ``/eve/collection`` as ``/eve`` will be stripped from ``PATH_INFO`` used to match paths in your application.

Comment: What do you mean by web framework? if I access `/collection` I get a 404 too (I edited the question to include the wsgi file)

Comment: From your WSGI file it looks like you may be using Flask. How did you set up the routes in your application file?

Comment: my run.py is `from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run()`

Comment: Create a new WSGI script file containing basic hello world app from http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html Then create a ``WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/hello.py`` for WSGI hello world in ``hello.py`` in some place. Also create a ``Directory`` block for directory to enable access to it. As that should intercept all requests for the site, if it still given 404, then there is something wrong with the ``VirtualHost`` setup and it is falling through to default ``VirtualHost``.